# How can i click this button and li with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I want to click this button and choose what i want the date selection.

My Document:

```
<div class="input-group-btn open">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">選取
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="mnuShowingDate" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">2017/07/29 (週六)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2017/07/30 (週日)</a>
      </li><li><a href="#">2017/07/31 (週一)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2017/08/01 (週二)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2017/08/02 (週三)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2017/08/03 (週四)</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I only know use the click function like this:

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.click('button.btn.btn-danger.dropdown-toggle');
});
```

It works , but i want to click the second li which is 2017/07/30 now.

How can i select it ?  Any ideas? Thanks in advance.